# Prestahop user info block login cache

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am facing seems like a bug of Prestashop(Some people claimed it to be)

1. I logged in to my website then even after I logged out, I am still logged in. But if I force refresh, then I am logged out. But if I come back to the page where I was logged in, I am come back again as logged in customer and can see the wholesale price.
2. In some pages, I am logged in as one of my customer which is weird. But only in a page that I assumed he/she logged in at ( do a test with a colleague in different computer, and she was logged in as me, when she accessed the page I logged in in different computer)

Can anyone help me?
I did a lot of debug but nothing seems to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: what is your server environment, default LAMP? Looks like with troubles sessions

Comment: Hi Sergii, we are on Cloud hosting with uber, their website described it as:  ....Utilising a clustered environment with intelligent load balancing and backed by an aggressive 99.99% Service Level Agreement (SLA), your site will deliver incredible performance and unparalleled levels of reliability.

Comment: hm, then I'll advice you to contact to service support, because bug that you described mostly appers with some cache configuration issues